# Way to select HTML tables by column and add them to the pasteboard?

Tags: safari, copy-paste, safari-extensions, html

Whenever you try to copy an HTML table to the pasteboard, it will select by row. Sometimes, I'd like to select by columns. Is there a way to do this? If not out of the box, any extensions that enable this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that in Safari or Chrome, but in Firefox you can select ranges of cells by holding option and command.

[image]

You could also copy the whole table and paste it to a spreadsheet application or use something like `pbpaste | cut -d $'\t' -f3`. But it might not work if there are cells that contain br elements or rows that start with empty cells.

I've had to use something like this with a few tables that contained br elements:

```
ruby -e '`pbpaste`.scan(/<tr>.*?<\/tr>/m).each { |r| puts r.scan(/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/m)[2] }'
```